# Constrain selected blocks by dragging up, down, and diagonal only. Building word search game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

[image]

As you can see, I'd like to make a row of blocks that I can select by dragging the mouse from one point to the other. You can only select the blocks perfectly up, down, or diagonal.

Fig1) The user has dragged from one corner to the other, creating a diagonal selection of the grid.

Fig2) The user has dragged past diagonal, so a third block isn't selected because it's not sure if they want to go straight down or diagonal.

Not sure how to go about this. This is a pretty complex interaction for me. Any tips or a point in the right direction would help.

Answer (score 0):

Each block should know what neighbors it has. For example, the top-left block should know that it has 3 neighbors (one to the east, one to the south-east, and one to the south).

Once the user has touched 2 blocks, you should be able to figure out what direction they're going in.

After that, they should only be able to touch blocks in that same direction from the previous block.

Example: Start on top-left block, move to the east for one block, and now you should only be able to move in an easterly direction from the previous block.

BTW, I'm not posting any code in this answer because you didn't post any in your question.